# Google Play button show me add card though there's a card added using pay flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, payment, google-pay

The button shows and everything but it shows me add card while there's a card, I'm trying the example from the pay package and still nothing changed, and even there's no error and I can't print out the data
I've 2 accounts registered on my device including the one who has card, I've tried to remove all accounts and keep the one that has a card but still didn't solve the issue

Here's the code

```dart
          GooglePayButton(
            paymentConfigurationAsset:
                'default_payment_profile_google_pay.json',
            paymentItems: _paymentItems,
            style: GooglePayButtonStyle.black,
            type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
            loadingIndicator: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
```

```dart
const _paymentItems = [
  PaymentItem(
    label: 'Total',
    amount: '99.99',
    status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
  )
];
```

Please help me because I'm stuck for this for days , I've even created an issue but no one answered me